# AJAX request not finishing due to PHP redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, redirect

**Background**

On my index page, I am trying to execute an ajax which makes entry in db tables.These table entries have to be made for every user visiting the website 
This index page is a login page and if user's session already exists then, this page redirect to the dashboard page of user.

**Problem**

Issue here is that if user has session active and s/he hit the index page, then page redirects before ajax "finishesh", so i am not able to get any entry in table.

Is there any way i can "wait" for the ajax to finish before redirecting or other way if i can let ajax "continue executing" even when page redirects??

Please note that i can not use jquery redirect as i have server level validation to redirect, so, client end won't serve a purpose.

Please have a look at code below :

```
<?php
if(!(isset($_GET['var']) && $_GET['var'] == 'logout')){
?>
    <!-- jQuery -->
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $.ajax({
            url: 'p/ajax_handler.php',
            data: 'ajax_action=tracker',
            type: 'post',
            success :function(data){
                data = data.trim();
                if(data != '1')
                    alert("something in backend went wrong, DB couldn't be updated"); 
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
                alert("Some ajax error occured, see console for details");
                console.log(xhr.statusText);
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(error);
            }
     }); 
    </script>


<?php
 //die("hi"); <-- if i un-comment this, ajax completes correctly as redirect is prevented
}
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_id']) && preg_match($pattern,$_SESSION['sess_id']))
{
    header('Location: p/main.php'); # <-- this is bummer
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you just do this?

```
<script>
$.ajax({
        url: 'p/ajax_handler.php',
        data: 'ajax_action=tracker',
        type: 'post',
        success :function(data){
            data = data.trim();
            if(data != '1')
                alert("something in backend went wrong, DB couldn't be updated");

            <?php
                if(isset($_SESSION['sess_id']) && preg_match($pattern,$_SESSION['sess_id'])) {
                    echo "$(location).attr('href','http://yoursite.com/p/main.php');";
                }
            ?>
        },
        error: function(xhr, textStatus, error){
            alert("Some ajax error occured, see console for details");
            console.log(xhr.statusText);
            console.log(textStatus);
            console.log(error);
        }
 }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could test if it's the ajax call and avoid redirecting case yes

```
if(isset($_SESSION['sess_id']) && preg_match($pattern,$_SESSION['sess_id']) 
&& !isset($_GET['ajax_action']))
{
    header('Location: p/main.php'); # <-- this is bummer
}
```